# NetBeans navigator window is empty

Tags: c, netbeans

I created a new C project from existing source files. NetBeans' navigator window is empty (NetBeans 8.2). See illustration below.

[image: NetBeans Navigator window is empty]

According to the section 'Using the Navigator Window' in [this NetBeans tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/navigating-editing.html),

> The Navigator window provides a compact view of the file that is currently selected, and simplifies navigation between different parts of the file.

The tutorial gives this screenshot as an illustration:

[image: Navigator window as per NetBeans tutorial]

Correspondingly, I'd expect my Navigator window to list the names of the functions and variables defined in the currently selected file.

Any ideas what's wrong, and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @KeineLust: Yes: how to fix it?

Comment: What are you expecting from this empty window? Give more details

Comment: @KeineLust: "The Navigator window provides a compact view of the file that is currently selected" [source](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/navigating-editing.html) I'm expecting a list of the functions and variables defined in the file, as in the screenshot in the link.

Comment: @KeineLust: I've added the details to my post, as well as an explicit question.

Answer (score 0):

I took the following steps, and the problem resolved.

1. Updated my NetBeans with the latest plugins.
2. Restarted NetBeans.
3. Rebuilt the project.

[image: Navigator's working!]

Comment: You should delete the netbeans cache folder (look at help>about to find it). That's how I fixed mine.